# Convert http to https using ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to convert `http` to `https` URL in Ruby.

Let me explain how my method works:

- List I'm sending post request to server to insert data into db and getting response as `http:devalphaserver.com/xxx/12`.
- If we hit this url it returns some data. I want this response url should convert `to https` (`https:devalphaserver.com/xxx/12`) in Ruby to do the Get Operation.

The issue which I'm facing now is when I try to do get operation using `http`, I'm getting 302 Found stating that The document has moved `https:devalphaserver.com/xxx/12` here.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Convert http to https using Ruby

```
url = "http:devalphaserver.com/xxx/12"
uri = URI.parse(url)
uri.scheme = "https"
uri.to_s
# => "https:devalphaserver.com/xxx/12"
```

However going through your question, I can see its a case of 302 redirect. If you are using gems like [REST Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) or [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) they have in place the mechanism of [result handling](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#user-content-result-handling) that takes care of url redirect automatically.

Comment: the result is still an instance of `URI::HTTP` instead of `URI::HTTPS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = "http:devalphaserver.com/xxx/12"
http_uri = URI(url)
https_uri = URI(http_uri.tap { |u| u.scheme = 'https' }.to_s)
```